# Cannot delete / ignore folder - keeps telling me I need to clean up

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, ignore

I have decided to remove the bin folder from one of my web apps from Source Control. It contains only external dlls which are stored in another folder anyway.

I right click and choose 'Delete and add to ignore list' but the error message below:

Directory 'C:\Kctc\Trunk\Moose\Bin\de is missing
Directory 'C:\Kctc\Trunk\Moose\Bin\de is missing
Please execute the 'Cleanup' command.

I can choose Cleanup on both the bin folder and the overall working copy folder and it tells me the process was successful, but when I try the 'Delete and add to ignore list' again I get the same error message.

Comment: I think I know why this has happened - as part of testing if I could remove the dlls from the bin folder, I completely emptied it and then rebuilt. So the .svn folder from the bin folder would have been deleted. But I have no idea what to do about it.

Comment: The standard solution for this error message is to Update the WC (It will bring back the missing folders).

Comment: I think that VirtualBlackFox's answer is the simplest, but I can't mark it becuase it's a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the whole working copy (e.g. rd /s /q ) and then checkout a new one.

If you have local modifications, copy those files out first, and then copy them into the new working copy.

> Right-click/TortoiseSVN/Check for
>   modifications